# disable module support in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

How to compile kernel without module support?

When I try disabling the "Enable Loadable module support" option and rebuild the kernel, I get following error:

```
Enable kernel module support and then compile the kernel
```

Comment: Have you disabled all modules before disabling module support ?

Comment: You can't build without module support if you are building modules! Easiest way would be to open the `.config` file and `s/=m/=y/`

Comment: I have disabled all modules before compilation and I have also checked .config file , there is not any =m option. I think I need to modify kernel.spec file as I ma compiling the kernel using kernel.spec file. And in kernel.spec file it is having options to build modules ,create directories etc. I am not getting in this file where all to make changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u share how you recompiling your kernel?

Comment: I am following http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel to rebuild the kernel.

Comment: Im not familar with fedor build system.i tried in ubuntu disabling modules ,its compiles without  any error

Comment: I am following above mentioned Fedora document. But I am working on RHEL6. With module support, I am able to compile it successfully but without module it giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Building a kernel without modules support requires you to have no `CONFIG` options selected as modules. These are the

With the kernel make-system you have `make mod2yesconfig` which sets all kernel modules to be built into kernel core. For a functioning system you might also want to do `make localyesconfig` which puts locally loaded modules into core. This way you don't forget to add some necessary drivers, for example block-device support or USB HID support.

You might come accross problems where a module built into core fails with code `-2` in kernel logs (available with `dmesg`). This implies a file could not be read and probably is caused by a disk containing firmware not yet being available during boot. This can be fixed by building in those firmwares into the kernel with option `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` which is a space separated list of the firmware file names under `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` (usually `/lib/firmware`). These options can be found under `Device Drivers -> Generic Driver Options -> Firmware loader -> Firmware loading facility` in `make nconfig`.

Many Linux distributions offer their own wrapping around the kernel make-system and finding your way to configure the `.config` file may be difficult. However you can always just use [kernel.org](https://kernel.org) sources which is a portable but arguably not that maintainable solution if not packaging those in the way your distribution does.